# Three colorings

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

One professor told his students he gave them a lot of money if they manage to find a graph $G=(V,E)$ with $30$ vertices satisfying the following conditions. Denote as $n_{u,v}$ the number of common neighbors of vertices $u$ and $v$, then

1. $\forall(\{u,v\}\in E):n_{u,v}=1$

This first condition means $G$ is locally linear. Let also $[n]=\{1,...,n\}$. Then there are two proper colorings $f:V\rightarrow [3]$, $g:V\rightarrow [5]$ and a coloring $h:V\rightarrow[2]$ such that

2. For all distinct $x,y\in[3]$, the induced subgraph $\langle f^{-1}(x)\cup f^{-1}(y)\rangle$ is $2$-regular.
3. $\forall(u,v\in V):u\neq v\wedge f(u)=f(v)\Rightarrow n_{u,v}≤1$
4. $\forall(x∈[3])\forall(y\in[5]):|f^{-1}(x)\cap g^{-1}(y)|=2$
5. $\forall(u,v\in V):u\neq v\wedge f(u)=f(v)\wedge g(u)=g(v)\Rightarrow n_{u,v}=0$
6. $\forall(x\in[3])\forall(y\in[5])\forall(z\in[2]):|f^{-1}(x)\cap g^{-1}(y)\cap h^{-1}(z)|=1$
7. $\forall(u,v\in V):f(u)\neq f(v)\wedge g(u)=g(v)\wedge h(u)=h(v)\Rightarrow n_{u,v}=0$

So far, one extraordinary student managed to find a graph $G=(V,E)$ with $30$ vertices and proper colorings $f:V\rightarrow [3]$ and $g:V\rightarrow [5]$ satisfying 1-5 (though he is not allowed to attach the image yet). He conjectured that one can not find the coloring $h$ (which is not necessarily proper), i. e. the original graph does not exist.

Comment: Hi, could you explain "why" ? As it stands, the problem lacks any context, it's just a list of conditions. What do they represent ? Why should we care about these ? Why is such graph interesting ?

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues I totally agree with you. As it stands, the problem is more like a math joke without a context. Briefly, it appears when dealing with strongly regular graphs $srg(x,y,1,2)$ and considering them as subgraphs of each other. We may assume then that the vertices are $n$-vectors which gives us $n$ colorings corresponding to the coordinates of vectors. Surprisingly, some of these colorings turn out to be proper and one may study how the colorings interact with each other instead of studying the graphs. Alas, the whole description is a bit huge to put it in the question.

Comment: Attaching the link to the student's graph. Here, vertices may have one of three shapes and five colors which corresponds to the codomain of $f$ and $g$. Note that our conditions imply $G$ is $4$-regular and contains no $4$-cycles. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kvEE0i2RHhqYWTR5F5Ayp-LPbcrwTWE2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I suggest indexing your vertices with triples $(a,b,c)$ with $a \in [3], b\in [5], c\in [2]$. There are $30$ such triples, so (4) and (6) are satisfied. Now backfill the edges to meet the remaining conditions. I also suggest translating the mathese into English as much as possible. For example, (7) says "no two vertices with the same $b, c$ values can have a common neighbor, and (5) says "no two vertices with the same $a, b$ values can have a common neighbor.

Comment: @PaulSinclair thanks for your time! I did start from the triples you suggest (as mentioned above) but it didn't give any ideas. Yes, it's probably better to use natural language when dealing with multiple conditions. Then we can state the question as a logical problem with $[2]$, $[3]$, $[5]$ denoting some sets of human's properties (say, gender, ethnicity, grades).

Comment: It suggests quite a lot to me. For all the talk of "proper" and "not proper" colorings, (6) actually requires exactly this representation, so all three colorings are necessarily proper. But instead of thinking of other ways to name the colors, I suggest just sticking with the numbers, and realizing this makes the vertices a rectangular grid of points in space. The "colors" are just coordinate values, and sets with one of the colors constant form a planar subgrid. (4) and (6) are satisfied, (2) says removing any of the three $x$-planes breaks the graph up into 1 or more disjoint cycles.

Comment: With (1), (5) and (7) imply that there are no edges parallel to the $x$ or $z$ axes ($y$ axis is still allowed), and (3) says you cannot have "bent quadrilaterals" with opposite vertices in the same $x$-layer.

Comment: @PaulSinclair this geometrical interpretation really makes sense. Though, "proper" means there are no two adjacent vertices with the same color. Didn't get how (6) implies it.

Comment: My apologies. "Proper" is used to describe many different things, so I had to search to figure out what it meant here. I thought I spotted it in a wikipedia article as meaning "using every color" (I.e. a "$k$-coloring" that isn't also a "$k-1$-coloring"). But they actually were just using "proper" without having defined it (not even with a link).

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found such a graph with $60$ edges (the minimum possible):

```
{(1,2),(1,24),(1,27),(1,29),(2,13),(2,15),(2,24),(3,10),(3,16),(3,17),(3,29),(4,11),(4,15),(4,23),(4,27),(5,9),(5,12),(5,16),(5,28),(6,7),(6,13),(6,14),(6,20),(7,8),(7,9),(7,14),(8,9),(8,21),(8,25),(9,16),(10,11),(10,12),(10,29),(11,12),(11,15),(12,28),(13,15),(13,20),(14,28),(14,30),(16,17),(17,19),(17,21),(18,19),(18,20),(18,22),(18,26),(19,20),(19,21),(21,25),(22,23),(22,26),(22,30),(23,27),(23,30),(24,25),(24,26),(25,26),(27,29),(28,30)}
```

The node colors are:

```
 i f g h 
 1 1 1 1 
 2 2 2 2 
 3 3 3 1 
 4 1 4 2 
 5 2 5 1 
 6 3 1 2 
 7 1 2 1 
 8 2 3 2 
 9 3 4 1 
10 1 5 2 
11 2 1 1 
12 3 2 2 
13 1 3 1 
14 2 4 2 
15 3 5 1 
16 1 1 2 
17 2 2 1 
18 3 3 2 
19 1 4 1 
20 2 5 2 
21 3 1 1 
22 1 2 2 
23 2 3 1 
24 3 4 2 
25 1 5 1 
26 2 1 2 
27 3 2 1 
28 1 3 2 
29 2 4 1 
30 3 5 2
```

It is indeed $4$-regular and contains no $4$-cycles.  The $h$-coloring cannot be proper because it would force $G$ to be bipartite whereas the first condition yields triangles for all nonempty $G$.

Comment: Sorry for not answering, need a little time to check this fantastic result! How did you manage to get it? I've used an improvised deep search in python, but it just gave the graph without $h$ I attached above.

Comment: I used integer linear programming.

Comment: I've checked it once more. Everything's correct. Thanks! Be sure, I will cite this result if I use it in my work (if you don't mind).

Comment: OK, but what about the money? :)

Comment: Sure! Going with my boys to the professor ;)

Comment: FYI, if you need an independent check, the example provided above is valid given my implementation of the problem.

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues thank you (I'd actually vote up comments if I had enough scores).

Comment: @RobPratt Sorry for taking your time again. Could you please give a hint what objective function you have optimized? It must be linear but the most obvious way to tell about common neighbors of two vertices is two consider the square of the adjacency matrix, which yields a non-linear function. Do we need to find the linear approximation of the last one? Again, sorry for my curiosity!

Comment: My main decision variables are binary $x_{ij}$ to indicate whether edge $(i,j)$ (with $i \not= j$) appears, and I have constraints $x_{ij}=x_{ji}$ to enforce symmetry.  My objective is to minimize $\frac{1}{2}\sum_i \sum_j x_{ij}$, but you can use any objective because you just want to find a feasible solution.  Yes, the number of common neighbors of $i$ and $j$ is the quadratic function $\sum_{k \not\in\{i,j\}} x_{ik} x_{jk}$, but this can be linearized exactly. See https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables

Comment: @RobPratt Got it, thanks for the details!